# I can't compile c++ code with cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I try to `cythonize` the following code:

```
from libcpp.vector import vector
from libcpp cimport bool

def test():
   cdef vector[bool] = pos(top, 0)

return 1
```

with:

```
cython test.pyx --cplus -o test.cpp
```

which however results in:

```
Error compiling Cython file:

------------------------------------------------------------

...

from libcpp.vector import vector
from libcpp cimport bool

def test():
cdef vector[bool] = pos(top, 0)
              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:5:19: Empty declarator

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from libcpp.vector import vector
from libcpp cimport bool

def test():
    cdef vector[bool] = pos(top, 0)
              ^
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I assume I'm missing something simple to use `c++` but I can't figure out what exactly. Any help would be greatly appropriated.

Comment: I know nothing about cython, but aren't you missing a name for the thing you're defining?

Comment: What is that `cdef` supposed to say.  It doesn't make sense as either Python or C / C++ to me.

Comment: @StephenC `cdef` is supposed to introduce c/c++ datatypes.

Comment: @StephenC: that's a cython definition, it gives python-like code c/c++ definitions for performance purposes, here's an example:  http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library

Comment: @Mat of course your totally right. I did screw up by the creation of the mwe. Thanks for solving the problem for me.

Comment: magu_ and Wolph ... I know that.  But the stuff after `cdef` is supposed to be a valid C / C++ declaration.  And it does not make sense as a C / C++ declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have 2 problems in your code:

1. the `vector` is imported using `import` instead of `cimport`.
2. the `vector[bool]` doesn't get a name, just a type definition.

Here's an example of working code for me:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef vector[bool] your_vector
```

Comment: Yes this was it. I don't know how I overlooked this. Thank you for pointing it out to me.